# Javascript google translator script

Tags: javascript, arrays

I really want to make a chrome addon that can translate marked text in a textbox (Very important that its a textbox) and replace the existing text with wanted language. So far I was thinking maybe something like this?

```
document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
range.deleteContents();
responseFromGoogle = 
document.createRange().createContextualFragment(<your translated 
response text here>);
range.insertNode(responseFromGoogle);
));
```

But I'm not sure if this will work and I'm not even sure how to make a function for a chrome addon so you can right click and press "replace marked text with the translation" or something.

I´d really appreciate some advice or maybe even help in doing so!